# Two submit form in a loop using php

Tags: php, html, forms

Does my code is correct to handle two submit form in a loop? I have this code but it doesn't get the second form. I mean it redirects to selectedSold.php but it doesn't view any detail or it doesn't get the `name="nganga"` of the selected row. In the first form it works then I decide to copy paste the code to selectedSold.php and then change a little bit of code in the select query but it doesn't show any result.

```
<?php foreach($articles as $a):?>
        <tr>
            <form method="post" action="selected.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="peopleName" value=" <?php echo $a['name']; ?>">
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" name="viewing">Ordered</button></td>
            </form>
            <form method="post" action="selectedSold.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="nganga" value=" <?php echo $a['name']; ?>">
                <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" name="psold">Bought</button></td>
            </form>
                <td><?php echo $a['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $a['contact'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $a['address'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $a['email'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $a['gender'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $a['datejoin'];?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>

    This is my query in first form ->
$articles = $db->prepare("
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ordered
        WHERE buyername='".$_POST['peopleName']."'
        LIMIT {$start}, {$perPage}
    ");
```

And this is my query in 2nd form

```
$articles = $db->prepare("
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS FROM `sold`
        WHERE buyername='".$_POST['nganga']."'
        LIMIT {$start}, {$perPage}
    ");
```

Comment: You want submit  `<td><?php echo $a['name'];?></td>` in `selectedSold.php` page?

Comment: Ýou can't. use a single form and a single php file to handle everything from that form.

Comment: That html is invalid. `<form>` can't be a child of `<tr>`. Browser will reject it and place it elsewhere and it may not even contain the form controls

Comment: yea mayank. my goal is to select list of item where name is like the value or the result of the query.

Comment: than write your submit button after all  `<td><?php echo $a['name'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $a['contact'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $a['address'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $a['email'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $a['gender'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $a['datejoin'];?></td>`

Comment: I think that your issue is with your HTML.  Its not valid.  You cannot put a `<form>` element around a `<td>`... as @charlietfl said

Comment: @MaggsWeb that's only part of the issue....you can't submit 2 forms either using default submit process. Only one form request is going to be made. Whatever logic on server that needs two submits  needs to be changed

Answer (score 0):

Don't put spaces around `<?php ... >?`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="peopleName" value="<?php echo $a['name']?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit 2 forms with one button, but you can have 2 (or more) forms in a loop submitting separately.  So presuming that you only want to submit one form at a time, this should fix your issue.  I have moved the `<forms>` inside the `<td>`s and changed the `<buttons>` to `<inputs>`.

```
<?php foreach($articles as $a):?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="selected.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="peopleName" value="<?=$a['name']?>">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" name="viewing" value="Ordered"/>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <form method="post" action="selectedSold.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="nganga" value="<?=$a['name']?>">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block" name="psold" value="Bought"/>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $a['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $a['contact'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $a['address'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $a['email'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $a['gender'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $a['datejoin'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

**Option 2 : for testing**

This would achieve the same effect, and could be used for testing a simplified version.

```
<?php foreach($articles as $a):?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="selected.php?peopleName=<?=$a['name']?>">Ordered</a>
    </td>

    <td>
        <a href="selectedSold.php?nganga=<?=$a['name']?>">Bought</a>
    </td>

    <td><?php echo $a['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $a['contact'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $a['address'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $a['email'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $a['gender'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $a['datejoin'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: yea i'm not trying to submit form at the same time.